ZAP Scan: Apex callout to our backend API
I am in the process of preparing materials for our security review submission. I have a case where our Apex code calls out to our backend API:

Directly from Apex code
Background job: Schedule, trigger or apex job

Could you please provide guidance on how to use the ZAP Scanner to scan/test this flow? For instance, in Screen A of the package, we make a callout to the backend API. Should I:

Open ZAP
Log in to our Salesforce
Navigate to this screen
Simulator the scenario, where the backend API callout occurs
ZAP scan

Is this the correct way to proceed? Considering that Salesforce encompasses not only our package but also many other stuffs/components, how can we ensure that the alerts are specific to our package and not related to other components?
For example, in my specific scenario, the ZAP report flagged an SQL Injection error
https://staging-manabie.lightning.force.com/aura?r=43-2&aura.DynamicComponent.getTemplateDescriptorWithExpansionBundle=1 



However, this request was not part of our code; it was triggered by Salesforce somewhere.
Do we need to fix it or document it as a false positive? Honestly, I'm not sure what the request does, so I don't know how to explain it.

Either use Chimera or use Zap with a simulation against your end point, perhaps using Postman.

Does this answer your question? How to OWASP ZAP scan external REST API using OAuth2

@PhilW It is not API-only. Should we replace the entire flow (without accessing the app on Salesforce) with Postman only? Additionally, do we need to use ZAP Scan for a 100% native Salesforce?

You use Zap to scan any custom REST APIs and UIs with custom components (or VF pages) to see if there are any vulnerabilities in this sort of code. Your external stuff can be scanned directly. The idea is to start with the URLs that Salesforce invokes, with any parameters Salesforce would send.

@PhilW ohm thank you got it

@PhilW Could you give me some hints on how to resolve the issue with script-src includes unsafe-eval when scanning UI components with ZAP? I don't see anywhere in the code where unsafe-eval is set in script-src. Any guidance on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. GET https://staging-manabie.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/MANAERP__Product__c/list?filterName=Recent HTTP/1.1
Referer: https://staging-manabie.file.force.com/?
file.force.com The domain file.force.com is not part of my code and I have no control over it.

I recommend asking a new question on that, and including the parts of the LWC/apex code that generates the URL and from what.
